# Preview view scanner stop working with fragment navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

I am working on an app that has a fragment with scanner implementation, when I scan some valid QRCODE, another fragment is called. When I back press to previous fragment the previewView stop working.
When working with Activities this doesn't happen.

Scanner Fragment

```
class ScannerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_scanner) {

    private val previewView by viewProvider<PreviewView>(R.id.preview_view)
    private var simpleScanner: SimpleScanner? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if (simpleScanner == null) {
            simpleScanner = SimpleScanner(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).also {
                it.setupListener(::onBarcodeCallback)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        simpleScanner?.start(previewView)
    }

    private fun onBarcodeCallback(value: String?) = value?.let {
        val action = ScannerFragmentDirections.actionScannerToSummary(it)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        simpleScanner?.stop()
        previewView.controller?.cameraInfo?.cameraState?.removeObservers(requireActivity())
        previewView.controller?.clearImageAnalysisAnalyzer()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Simple Scanner

```
class SimpleScanner(private val activity: AppCompatActivity) {

    private val cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    private val permissionContractActivity =
        activity.registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { permissionCallback }

    var permissionCallback: ((Boolean) -> Unit)? = null
    var supportedBarcodeList: Array<Int> = arrayOf(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
    var onDetectedBarcodeListener: ((String?) -> Unit)? = null

    private var isListenerCalled: Boolean = false

    fun start(previewView: PreviewView) {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            isListenerCalled = false
            initiate(previewView)
        } else {
            permissionContractActivity.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    fun setupListener(listener: (String?) -> Unit) {
        onDetectedBarcodeListener = listener
    }

    private fun checkPermissions() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun callbackManager(value: String?) = value?.let {
        if (!isListenerCalled) {
            isListenerCalled = true
            onDetectedBarcodeListener?.invoke(it)
        }
    }

    private fun initiate(previewView: PreviewView) {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(activity)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            kotlin.runCatching {
                val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

                val preview = Preview.Builder().build().apply {
                    setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                }

                val analyzer = CodeScannerAnalyzer(
                    supportedBarcodeList.toIntArray(),
                    activity
                ) { value ->
                    callbackManager(value)
                }

                val codeAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.clearAnalyzer()
                        it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, analyzer)
                    }

                val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    activity,
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview,
                    codeAnalyzer
                )
            }.onFailure {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", it)
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity))
    }

    companion object {
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = mutableListOf(
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        )
    }
}
```

I already try to move simpleScanner.stop() function into different lifecycle methods. Is working well in Activity.
I'm expecting that the scanner comes back when I back press from fragment B.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).